# Адаптивная таблица для телефона и ПК

Tags: css, media-queries, адаптивность

Есть данная адаптивная таблица для телефона и ПК, из четырех колонок. Все хорошо НО применить CSS не возможно (кроме font-size), так как все сразу ломается.
Предложите пожалуйста аналог, НО чтобы работали все стили CSS.

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
} 

.col {
  width: 25%;
}
    
    
@media(max-width:400px){
    .col{
      width: 50%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="col">ПАПЕ</div>
  <div class="col">МАМЕ</div>
  <div class="col">СЫНУ</div>
  <div class="col">ДОЧЕРИ</div>
<div>
```

Comment: что именно ломается?

Comment: Да, ввот я тоже не понял. Приведите пример

Comment: flex-wrap: wrap уберите, .col сделать width: 100%; text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае я бы посоветовал использовать гриды вместо флекса.

```css
.block {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
 
.col {
       border: 1px solid Black;  
}         
    
@media(max-width:400px){

    .wrapper {
       display: grid;
       grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
       grid-gap: 5px;
       grid-auto-rows: minmax(45px, auto);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="col">ПАПЕ</div>
  <div class="col">МАМЕ</div>
  <div class="col">СЫНУ</div>
  <div class="col">ДОЧЕРИ</div>
<div>
```

Comment: @letUserВы пробовали нажать кнопку "Выполнить код"? Слова не по центру.